# Ajax, not as post or get?

Tags: php, ajax

I have been using Ajax mainly to be used as a POST, to take care of thinks, but now wanted just to open a simple login page into a DIV (and is doing it) but now the problem comes when I have added this to the PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST))
{

}
else
{
    echo "
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset='utf-8'>
            <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='assets/css/main.css'>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class='page-header'>
                <h1>Preencha os campos e carregue em enviar</h1>
            </div>
            <form>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='exampleInputEmail1'>Endereço Email</label>
                    <input type='email' class='form-control' id='exampleInputEmail1' placeholder='Email'>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Palavra-Pass</label>
                    <input type='password' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' placeholder='Palavra-Pass'>
                </div>
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Enviar</button>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>";
}
```

and this is the Ajax code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.navmenu a').bind('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var urlToGo = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($( window ).width() <= "992" && !$(this).hasClass('dropdown-toggle'))
        {
            $('.navmenu').offcanvas('hide');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: urlToGo,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(result)
            {
                $(".container").html(result);
            }
        });
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 700);
        console.log(urlToGo);
    });
});
```

When I press the link to be used to use the Ajax, it will put a empty page on the div container, what I'm doing wrong in here? If I Change the (isset($_POST)) to (!isset($_POST)) it will show the content right, and I don't wanted this to be a post.

What is wrong in the logic here ?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try manually setting the the ajax request to POST? `method:"POST"`

Comment: advice:  jquery ajax have type 'GET' by default.

Comment: @daremachine Ya notice that with the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] that  told me to be more precise to judge what was being doing "on background" I wanted is to be a simple load of a page to a specif div, don't wanted a GET or a POST method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$_POST` is a global variable of PHP, it exists in every php thread, so `isset($_POST)` will return `true`, in your example the value of `$_POST` is an empty array. You can have a try like blow:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

} else {
    echo 'your html'
}
```

By the way , I think  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is a more precise way to judge what kind of http request method the request is used.

Comment: I did use the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] to see what method was get, what I want in here, is not to be a POST or GET method, Just wanted to load the page of the link as it is

Comment: You can set the div to invisible in the html, and then  load it using javascript, it not need ajax communicating with php,

Comment: That could work, just needed to load that div into the div container, or I could use your advice on the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] and if it is a GET (Like the default of ajax) it will go to the else.

Wanted is to have the form and verification on the same file for the login, just to more easy to find if needed, thats why I'm loading this file into a DIV to take care for this hehe.

Thanks for the help